# How reduce resolution of a graph during export?

Tags: graphics, export, image

Suppose I have a density plot which I want to export in EPS format. But when  tried using  command, Export["/home/1.eps", %263, "EPS"] , the exported image has very large size (~100MB). How can I export the image with a size ~1 MB? Someone kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: try the option `ImageResolution` with different settings in `Export`, e.g. `plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis];
Export["plotir20.eps", plot, ImageResolution -> 20];
Export["plotir100.eps", plot, ImageResolution -> 100];`?

Comment: If you can, try to export to PDF instead. That applies automatic image compression.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your reply solved my problem.

Comment: atanu, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the option [`ImageResolution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageResolution.html) in `Export`:

```
plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis];
```

Compare the two files:

```
Export["plot20.eps", plot, ImageResolution -> 20] 

Export["plot100.eps", plot, ImageResolution -> 100]
```

Comment: Yes. I have tried it and it works fine. Thanks for the reply.